# Get array of repositoryOwner from GitHub GraphQL

Tags: graphql, github-api

I have this query:

```
query { 
  repositoryOwner(login: "jcubic") {
    repositories(first: 20, orderBy: {field: STARGAZERS, direction: DESC}, privacy: PUBLIC) {
      edges {
        repository:node {
          name
          stargazers {
            totalCount
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

is it possible to get multiple users intead of single one?

Comment: Do you have a list of the node ids for the repository owners that you which to perform the query for?

Comment: @BenWhale what basically I want is `login: ["jcubic", "lorvalds"]` or `login: /^ab.*/` if this is not possible then GraphQL is not as good as eveyone says. It's pretty usesless if I need to run 100 queries to get 100 users.

Comment: @BenWhale but if it's possible with id, then I'm fine. I can save id when I'm first query for the users, next time I will have id.

Comment: The issue for you is what fields the query object has. Check out: https://developer.github.com/v4/query/#fields. There is a nodes field that will return multiple nodes given the ids. There is also a search connection which appears to require a cursor?

Comment: @BenWhale sorry I don't understand those docs, it seems that they say that `codeOfConduct` have key. so you can search codeOfConduct which is useless, why I want to search that I want users.

Comment: @BenWhale thanks for your answer, it seems that there is Node that have ID as list and Node is also User that is repository owner. Will try to figure that one by myself from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from, I was able to create query using IDs (they are from me and linus torvalds):

```
{
  nodes(ids: ["MDQ6VXNlcjI4MDI0MQ==", "MDQ6VXNlcjEwMjQwMjU="]) {
    ... on User {
      name
      login
    }
    ... on RepositoryOwner {
      repositories(first: 20, orderBy: {field: STARGAZERS, direction: DESC}, privacy: PUBLIC) {
        edges {
          repository: node {
            name
            stargazers {
              totalCount
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```